# Bootstrap modal call from fullcalendar event click

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar on my page. On it I have an add event button. That calls a javascript function that opens a modal view allowing the user to add an event.

```
function showAddMeeting() {
    var current_date = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
    $("#modal").load('modal.php?type=meeting&action=add&date='+current_date);
}
```

This works perfectly. Now, I have another function to edit the meeting:

```
function showEditMeeting(meeting_id) {
    alert('modal.php?type=meeting&action=edit&id='+meeting_id);
    $("#modal").load('modal.php?type=meeting&action=edit&id='+meeting_id);
}
```

When I put this on the button, it works fine. But when I add it as a function to the event, it does not work.

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    showEditMeeting(event['id']);
}
```

When I click the event, I get the alert of the working link, but I never get a modal popover.

EDIT:

I've figured out it's because I'm not calling

```
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"
```

Does anybody know of how to call that through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has all the methods available for the modal in "modal.js", this is included in the minified pack.

You need to use it as follows.

**Original**

```
function showEditMeeting(meeting_id) {
    alert('modal.php?type=meeting&action=edit&id='+meeting_id);
    $("#modal").load('modal.php?type=meeting&action=edit&id='+meeting_id);
}
```

**Becomes**

```
function showEditMeeting(meeting_id) {
    alert('modal.php?type=meeting&action=edit&id='+meeting_id);
    $("#modal").load('modal.php?type=meeting&action=edit&id='+meeting_id).modal('show');
}
```

Notice the additional .modal('show');

Please note, I've not tested this code.

More information: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods